# Pure Javascript for Image or DIV Flip

Tags: javascript, html, css, flip

As i need to code html in my software so i `need only pure javascript` for fliping.

Please no css animation or Jquery animation, only pure javascript.

need similar to  : http://pingmin-tech.com/flipcardjs

found one solution here : 
**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5jwa5jo8)**

but it will be better if i get similar to http://pingmin-tech.com/flipcardjs

Comment: javascript must before your html code

Answer (score 5):

javascript before your html code.

and this link is the answer your asked me below comments:
https://jsfiddle.net/ws7054r2/

```css
#card {
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 25px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<script>
  var k = 0;

  function flip() {
    var j = document.getElementById("card");
    k += 180;
    j.style.transform = "rotatey(" + k + "deg)";
    j.style.transitionDuration = "0.5s"
  }
</script>
<div id="card" onmouseover="flip()">sample text</div>
```

Comment: i used a alert function inside flip function and its working, this was the alert  :  alert("Hello! I am an alert box!!");

Comment: working for me but no effects  '<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
<!-- hide from none JavaScript Browsers
    Image1 = new Image(75, 50)
    Image1.src = "DELETE16.PNG"
    Image2 = new Image(75, 50)
    Image2.src = "CREATE16.PNG"
    function SwapOut() {
        document.imageflip.src = Image2.src; return true;
    }
    function SwapBack() {
        document.imageflip.src = Image1.src; return true;
    }
    // - stop hiding -->
</SCRIPT>
      <A HREF="index.html" onMouseOver="SwapOut()" onMouseOut="SwapBack()"> 
<IMG NAME="imageflip" SRC="CREATE16.PNG" WIDTH=75 HEIGHT=50 BORDER=0></A>'

Comment: @wasimjee please show your code on jsfiddle or else. Your comment is really hard to read.

Answer (score 1):

Buddy if you want the same thing as given in the link then you must use the jQuery file and the given css.

What is the problem in using the files?

The link you have provided has full code and demo on performing what you want, just use it.

It is much better as compared to any other alternate way to achieve what you want.

Comment: ya , its working in the html, but i am including this html file inside my software, what i see is the problem with css

Comment: I am using this code and its working fine  :  http://www.dhtmlgoodies.com/index.html?whichScript=xp_info_pane