# Flipping a div by class name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation

I'm trying to flip a div on mouseover, I found a few pages really useful.

[followed this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15754859/how-to-set-id-using-javascript) to set ID and then according to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28492791/pure-javascript-for-image-or-div-flip) I need to add the mouseover property in the HTML but it's not easy as the ID.

Here is my code so far:

```
var abcElements = document.querySelectorAll('.builder_row_cover');

for (var i = 0; i < abcElements.length; i++)
  abcElements[i].id = 'abc-';
var oHover = document.getElementById("abc-");
oHover.setAttribute("onmousehover", "flip()");


var k = 0;

function flip() {
var j = document.getElementById("abc-");
k += 180;
j.style.transform = "rotatey(" + k + "deg)";
j.style.transitionDuration = "0.5s"
}
```

I'm just starting, I have tried with setting attribute, but no way to see the mouseover in the HTML, any suggestion?

Comment: You're giving multiple elements the same ID, but IDs need to be unique.

Comment: onmouse**h**over isn't a valid event

Answer (score 0):

First, the name of the event is `onmouseover`.

Giving multiple elements the same ID won't work. `document.getElementById()` will just return the first element with that ID, not the one that the mouse is over.

You don't need to use the ID at all. You can use `this` in the event handler to refer to the target of the event.

```
var abcElements = document.querySelectorAll('.builder_row_cover');

for (var i = 0; i < abcElements.length; i++) {
  abcElements[i].addEventListener('mouseover', flip);
}

var k = 0;

function flip()
    k += 180;
    this.style.transform = "rotatey(" + k + "deg)";
    this.style.transitionDuration = "0.5s";
}
```